# invalidating a timer blocks my app

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I have done the following:

*header file*

```
 NSTimer *timer1;
 NSTimer *timer2;
```

*implementation file*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(!timer1)
        timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target: self selector: @selector(repeatRequest) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

    if(!timer2)
        timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.

    [timer1 invalidate];
    [timer2 invalidate];

}
```

So when I leave the current view these two lines make my app crash:

```
 [timer1 invalidate];
        [timer2 invalidate];
```

Anyone any idea why?Or does someone know any other method to stop the timer when I leave the current view?Thank you

EDIT:
timer2 calls this method:

```
- (void) repeatRequest{
    NSLog(@"backgroundRequest");
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backgroundRequest) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

which does a `ASIHTTPRequest` at server side.

now I kept only:

```
[timer1 invalidate];
```

and it doesn't block anymore...but what I do with timer2?

Comment: Are the timers sending messages before the view disappears?

Answer (score 3):

these 2 lines actually should not be bad -  in case you dealloc the viewcontroller and therefore the view disappears.

if you can switch back to your view, viewDidLoad is NOT beeing called. in that case, timer1 and timer2 are, as logancautrell said, dangling.

so what you want to try is:

```
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

     [timer1 invalidate];
     timer1 = nil;

     [timer2 invalidate];
     timer2 = nil;
 }
```

as well as moving

```
  if(!timer1)
         timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target: self selector: @selector(repeatRequest) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

   if(!timer2)
         timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

to your

```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

then it should not trouble you.

Comment: try: if(timer1){[timer1 invalidate]; timer1=nil;} + same for timer2 ? (dont know other code you evetually have)

Comment: can you ensure, that viewWillDisappear is called? its for UINavigationControllers and some others, not for all kind of VC iirc. try viewDidDisapper instead if its just a UIVC.

Comment: yes, i put a message.and it gets called.It blocks because I invalidate the timer.If I comment these lines then it works!

Comment: can you provide full information then what "blocking" means in your case? error? crash? message? or does it just hang?

Comment: it crashes.EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal appears!

Comment: okay, please remove if(!timer1) and if(!timer2) from viewDidLoad unless you did you set them to initial-nil or using ARC. reason:
NSTimer *a; if(a) NSLog(@"foo"); <- can work! a is now just an invalid pointer, but not nil!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4730/discussion-between-george-and-dhanke)

Comment: i think ur doing wrong with threads execution... ,wht r u doing in ontimer

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the timer ivars to nil whenever you invalidate. Otherwise you have a dangling pointer.

Comment: the thing is that even if I invalidate the timer...the method trigger by the timer still gets called.any idea why?